# Azure AD B2C iframe - CORS frame-ancestor localhost

Tags: iframe, cors, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Trying to follow the steps to setup AADB2C using an `iframe`. Got the custom policy working, and we're able to get the basic part of the `iframe` working too. The problem is that we're trying to debug this on localhost, and we're getting a pile of CORS-related errors, foremost being the `frame-ancestor` error when the login process completes and AADB2C redirects back to our site.

Wondering if there are any steps we can take to resolve this locally. I know that MSFT requires custom domains (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) in order to make this process work cleanly; unfortunately that requires Azure Front Door, which, while we'll definitely need when we put this into production, is a bit heavy-handed for localhost debugging for a proof-of-concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a giant red-herring. The errors were due to the site being rendered as `http` when running locally, while the custom policy was restricting to `https`.